# How to prevent animated div from expanding several times after several clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of with each list item expanding upon being clicked and then shrinking after being clicked again with an animation which lasts 200ms. This works okay but when if the user were to click the list item several times in a short time interval, it attempts to catch up with the user in a way which causes it to expand and contract several times over quite a long period of time, which looks very buggy.

Here is my HTML

```
<ul id="cons">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

(My list items are styled to appear as coloured blocks)

And my JavaScript

```
  Array.from(document.getElementById('cons').children).forEach((item, index) => {
      function toggleForward(item) {
        return () => {
          $(item).animate({height: '400px'}, 400)
          $(item).off('click').click(toggleBackward(item))
        }
      }
      function toggleBackward(item) {
        return () => {
          $(item).animate({height: '50px'}, 400)
          $(item).off('click').click(toggleForward(item))
        }
      }
      $(item).click(toggleForward(item))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry about that, I misunderstood your question.

This should do it, though:

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

```js
$("#cons").children().each((index, item) => {
  let itemToggler = new Toggler(item, 400, '100px', 'no-cursor');
  $(item).on('click', event => itemToggler.toggle())
});

function Toggler(item, duration, maxToggleHeight, noCursorClass) {
  this.item = item;
  this.toggled = false;
  this.noCursorClass = noCursorClass;
  this.maxToggleHeight = maxToggleHeight;
  this.duration = duration;
  this.originalHeight = $(item).height();

  this.toggle = () => {
    $(this.item).addClass(this.noCursorClass);
    $(this.item).animate({
      height: this.toggled ? this.originalHeight : this.maxToggleHeight
    }, {
      duration: this.duration,
      complete: () => {
        $(this.item).removeClass(this.noCursorClass);
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.no-cursor {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on an item</p>
<ul id="cons">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

***UPDATED ANSWER***: as a jQuery plugin:

```js
MakePlugin();

$("#cons").children().each((ndx, itm) => {
  $(itm).clickToggler({
    cursorClass: "cursor-pointer",
    noCursorClass: "cursor-not-allowed",
    maxToggleHeight: '100px',
    duration: 400
  });
});


// The plugin is only wrapped in this MakePlugin() function
// so I could put it below the 'main logic' above.
function MakePlugin() {


  // Main 'clickToggler' plugin:
  (function($) {
    $.fn.clickToggler = function(options) {
      let settings = $.extend({
          toggled: false,
          cursorClass: "",
          noCursorClass: "",
          maxToggleHeight: '10px',
          duration: 100
        }, { 
          originalHeight: $(this).height(),
          ...options 
        }
      );

      $(this).on("click", event => {
        if(!$(this).is(':animated')) {
          $(this).addClass(settings.noCursorClass);
          $(this).animate({
            height: settings.toggled ? settings.originalHeight : settings.maxToggleHeight
          }, {
            duration: settings.duration,
            complete: () => {
              $(this).removeClass(settings.noCursorClass);
              settings.toggled = !settings.toggled;
            }
          });
        }
      });
      
      return settings.cursorClass
        ? $(this).addClass(settings.cursorClass)
        : this;
    };
  })(jQuery);
  
  
}
```

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor-not-allowed {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on an item</p>
<ul id="cons">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but in your code the items retract immediately after expanding, but I need them to retract only after being clicked again

Comment: @Tom888 Sorry about that I misunderstood your question.. I also showed how you can change the cursor during animation to make it more evident that you can't click while animating.

Comment: That's okay. And yes that was helpful, I will add that in now and I'll also change my method of collecting the child elements to use jquery. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom888 I just updated my answer to show how you can handle this without having to continue to remove and then re-add events after each click. Removing and re-adding events uses I/O that doesn't need to be used.. can be considered 'wasteful'..

Comment: @Tom888 I also provided a new Snippet to show how you can turn this into an custom jQuery plugin, which seems best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The trick was to ask whether the item was already animated, and only animating it on click if it was not already mid animation. This way animations did not "stack up" on each other requiring it to catch up. So, I changed my code to this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementById('cons').children).forEach((item, index) => {
    function toggleForward(item) {
      return () => {
        if(!($(item).is(':animated'))) {
          $(item).animate({height: '400px'}, 400)
          $(item).off('click').click(toggleBackward(item))
        }
      }
    }
    function toggleBackward(item) {
      return () => {
        if(!($(item).is(':animated'))) {
          $(item).animate({height: '50px'}, 400)
          $(item).off('click').click(toggleForward(item))
        }
      }
    }
    $(item).click(toggleForward(item))
})
```